# How to return a non-nullable type from a Function in a function callback?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

```dart
Future<int> getInt() async { // Error: 
  final c = Completer<int>();
  await foo.bar(
    callback1: (i) => c.complete(i),
    callback2: (j) => c.complete(j),
    error: (e) => throw e,
  );
}
```

> The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type.

As I know one of these callback will work, so how do I tell the analyzer that I've handled all the scenarios?

Note: I know I can simply use `Future<int?>` but I want to know if there are other ways of handling this case?

Comment: You are not returning anything yet which is, by default, returning null. But according to the function signature, `Future<int>`, a non-null return value, an `int`, is expected. You can solve it by properly returning an `int`.

Comment: Unless you use Future<int?> as you already know, you must return something, which can be `return c;` at the end.

Comment: @saw I am aware of these rules, check the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analyzer is right here, you're just not returning anything from `getInt()`.

Add `return completer.future` at the end of `getInt()`.

Note:
Using `Completer` here seems rather odd, it's mainly used to bridge between callback-based API and `Future`-based API.

Answer (score 0):

You need a return statement:

```
final result = await foo.bar(
  callback1: (i) => c.complete(i),
  callback2: (j) => c.complete(j),
  error: (e) => throw e,
);
return result;
```

OR

```
...
return c;
```

Comment: `foo.bar` doesn't return `int`.

Comment: I wasn't sure how's he's gonna get his return value. So I listed all possibilities. :)